# How to download excel files generated by node [Node][Angular]

Tags: angularjs, node.js, excel, xlsx

I use the same way it's mentioned in [[Node][Angular] How to download excel files generated by node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200830/nodeangular-how-to-download-excel-files-generated-by-node) 
but still I don't get any popup to open or save. I could see the buffer in the Network window of Chrome.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side you can use:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
 success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    const fileName = `file.xlsx`;
    let file = new File([blob], fileName);
    let fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
 });
```

I used File because it allows you to pass filename. You could skip this part and pass Blob to `URL.createObjectURL`. It opens window with download. Assuming your server code is correct. But if you see buffer in Chrome than it sends something.

For server side I usually use  express [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile). It needs you to create a file so you gave to clean up.

Comment: How to download the filestream of xlsx from nodejs in AngularJS Client side? Anyidea?